# Qt instant object intercommunication in GUI

Tags: c++, qt

In this trivial example, pushButton1_clicked() alters the text of a QLabel by the setText() method:

```
void MainWindow::pushButton1_clicked()
{
    ui->label1->setText("BLABLABLA");
    Sleep(5000);
}
```

Here, label1 Text will be set to "BLABLABLA", but ONLY AFTER pushButton1_clicked() has finished (after 5 seconds). Why's that? I want it to be altered the same moment setText() method is called and only then the thread can sleep for 5 seconds. How is it done in Qt?

Thanks in advance.

ps. Using Qt 5.2 with Visual Studio 2012 compiler.

Comment: Are you saying that pushButton1_clicked() is a slot, and it's in a secondary thread?

Comment: @MrEricSir pushButton1_clicked() is a slot by default but it's not in a 2nd thread. There isn't much to it, I just created a new Qt Widgets Application project and added a QPushButton and a QLabel to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Sleep` method blocks the GUI thread for 5 seconds. You should **never** block the GUI thread. While `Sleep` executes, nothing else in the same thread will run, save for native asynchronous procedure calls. The `setText` method merely *schedules* a widget update, it doesn't repaint the widget at that very moment. Since `Sleep` prevents the control from returning to the event loop, the scheduled update won't happen.

If you want to delay the execution of some task after the button was pressed, you should use a timer:

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
  QScopedPointer<Ui::MainWindow> ui;
  ...
  Q_SLOT void pushButton1_clicked() {
    ui->label1->setText("Waiting...");
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, this, SLOT(postWait()));
  }
  Q_SLOT void postWait() {
    ui->label1->setText("Finished waiting.");
  }
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow(this)) {}
  ~MainWindow() {} // The smart pointer will delete the child widgets automatically
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about the order of operations here:

- The GUI emits a signal change event for the button push
- Your slot is invoked
- From within your slot, you're queuing a widget update event
- You then halt the main event loop for 5 seconds
- Once the execution returns to the main event loop, it can update the screen

This is pretty typical behavior any type of GUI on any platform.  Locking the GUI thread is considered poor practice -- users don't expect the interface to lock up.  Instead, you should use a [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTimer.html), which will not block the main event loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's my first answer in stackoverflow, I register today, so excuse me if I do something wrong.
Sleep freeze all your app, so you can use QTest::qWait
For example

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
    ui->label->setText("BLABLABLA"); //now we change the text
     //Sleep(5000);
    QTest::qWait(5000); //waiting, nothing happened
    qDebug() << "5 sec gone";//after 5 sec we can see this words
}
```

Comment: This is bad advice. `qWait` spins an event loop and will happily reenter the application code that you don't expect to be reentered. Never mind that you bring in a heavy testing module into a production application.